# Is it possible to use in perf as sampling period the number of cycles?

Tags: cycle, performancecounter, sampling, perf, period

I have tried to measure the performance counters using `perf` for different sampling periods and for this I used the `-I` option. But this measures the sampling interval in milliseconds.

Is it possible to use with `perf` a sampling interval measured in cycles so that we get the information about performance counters every X number of cycles (i.e. collect information periodically)?

Comment: I don't think so. In the `perf` as an software program, you don't have a control about the number of cycles elapsed, especially on architectures with some way of Turbo frequency scaling. Otherwise you can recalculate the time to the cycles, but it will not be ideal.

Comment: Yes, I considered recalculating the time in cycles, but I also thought it wasn't the best idea.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the `-c` option in `perf` is for? Something like `perf record -e cycles -c 200` should sample every 200 cycles?

Comment: -c is used to collect a sample every 200 occurrences of the event specified. In the case you mentioned, it works, but if I want to measure more performance counters (e.g. `perf record -e cycles,instructions -c 200`) it would sample every 200 occurrences of cycles for cycles and every 200 occurrences of instructions for instructions and that is not what I want. I want all performance counters to be sampled based on the number of cycles.